# Webpack - Determine why a file is included

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack config with some loaders and plugins.  These loaders have some include/test/exclude rules.

However, a set of files keep being included in the webpack build.  They're not imported anywhere which means it's likely some bad config.

Is there a way to ask webpack WHY a file is included in a build?

Comment: Maybe it can help you [webpack analyzer](https://webpack.github.io/analyse)

Comment: Can you share you webpack.config file?

Comment: Hi @voro, how will this help?  This is across all webpack configurations for any project.  I'm interested in how you can find out why webpack is including a file in general, not for a specific setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some Display Options you can set when running webpack that can help you with what you want to achieve. Check them [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#display-options).

There is a specific one, `--display-reasons` that will show the reasons why a module is included, or at least more information about why it is included.
Also this one: `--display-modules` may be interesting to show modules that are hidden from the output by default because they come from directories like node_modules or bower_components.

I hope this helps.

Comment: that's a 404 on the link.

Comment: and https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/ does not show anything about --display options.  Using webpack 5 in my case.  I'll add more info if I find anything else but right now this looks out of date.  How I ran webpack was `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.dev.js` and then tried those flags.  That's why it's good to flesh out answers a bit, besides providing a link.  Searching the output of verbose help via `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --help=verbose` didn't show anything either.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more about what set of files are being included, I'd suggest setting:

```
stats: 'verbose'
```

in your [webpack config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats). Depending on the size of your app, this may dump *a lot* of info, but it should display where a given file or files is/are being included from. The [`stats`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats) config object can also be tailored to display more specific info.

Comment: The output from this doesn't look helpful for answer the OP's question unless you are an expert in internal webpack implementation details.